# What JavaScript library can you recommend?

Tags: javascript

I want to use JavaScript on my web page. In particular I would like to have a auto-completer (like stackoverflow use for tags). I also would like to have drop down menus and so on.

I think, for these purposes it make sense to use a JavaScript library (I never did it before).  I browsed Internet the first option that I found was jQuery, I also found a list of [other libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries).

So, I have a hard time choosing between these libraries and would like to ask your advise. My requirements to the library as as follow:

1. Of course cross-browser functionality (works on as many browsers as possible).
2. Easy to use (good documentation with examples + active community).
3. Possibility to change the code (corresponding copy right + good documentation of the code).

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: This is a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913/what-javascript-library-would-you-choose-for-a-new-project-and-why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go for [jquery](http://jquery.com/) and [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) which contains a nice [autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). It's a javascript framework which gathered lots of pace, there's an enormous community and it is very likely you will find a plugin for every needs. It is guaranteed to work cross browser and you get a great documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, if I type "d" there i get "Cold Fusion" (but I expect to get words starting from d).